# Use Mule data mapper in embedded mode

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Is there a constraint on using Mule data mapper in embedded mode. My application is deployed as WAR file in tomcat. Can I use data mapper in that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need data mapper runtimes also on the container you're running application in. `Data mapper` uses `Clover engine` runtimes. `Mule EE` container is equipped with it.

As, Data Mapper is an **enterprise only** feature and you'd have Mulesoft support if you're planning to use it, its best to log a ticket with them. In my experience you won't be able to successfully deploy application in tomcat for data mapper feature without add-ons