# Facing issue while deploying webapp on tomcat: Mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I tried to deploy my webapp as tomcat service. I follow this link https://github.com/ddossot/mule-in-action/tree/mule-3/chapter07/web-application
Following is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>salesforce</display-name>
    <description>salesforce to ftp</description>



    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
        <param-value>javatest.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleRESTReceiverServlet</servlet-class>

        <!-- Responses from the servlet are of type HTML by default -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.mule.servlet.default.content.type</param-name>
            <param-value>text/html</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>testindex.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And following is my javatest.xml file

```
<data-mapper:config name="CSV_To_List_Transaction_c" transformationGraphPath="csv_to_list_transaction_c.grf" doc:name="CSV_To_List_Transaction"/>
    <sfdc:config name="Salesforce" username="username" password="pwd" doc:name="Salesforce" securityToken="token"/>
     <flow name="javatestFlow1" doc:name="javatestFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="Custom" moveToDirectory="Backup" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_List_Transaction_c" doc:name="CSV To List&lt;Transaction_c&gt;"/>

        <sfdc:create-bulk config-ref="Salesforce" type="Transaction__c" doc:name="Salesforce">
            <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
        </sfdc:create-bulk>
        <idempotent-message-filter idExpression="#[payload.state]" doc:name="Idempotent Message"/>
        <custom-transformer class="com.org.Status" doc:name="Java"/>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="test..."/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>

<flow name="testforceFlow1" doc:name="testforceFlow1">
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/download" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Servlet"/> 
         <flow-ref name="javatestFlow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</flow>
```

When I deploy this app at that time I got following error

```
WARN  2015-03-05 19:25:56,228 [main] org.eclipse.jetty: Error creating bean with name 'javatestFlow1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#e93ee6' of type [com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.processors.DataMapperMessageProcessor] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e93ee6': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mulesoft.datamapper.exception.DataMapperRuntimeException: The data mapping graph csv_to_list_transaction_c.grf does not exists (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'javatestFlow1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#e93ee6' of type [com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.processors.DataMapperMessageProcessor] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e93ee6': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mulesoft.datamapper.exception.DataMapperRuntimeException: The data mapping graph csv_to_list_transaction_c.grf does not exists (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
```

I want to deploy this app on tomcat server as service,
How can I solve this error?? Please help

Thanks

Comment: I think this is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373587/use-mule-data-mapper-in-embedded-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of the exception is:

```
com.mulesoft.datamapper.exception.DataMapperRuntimeException
The data mapping graph csv_to_list_transaction_c.grf does not exists
```

To fix the issue, make sure that you are correctly packaging `csv_to_list_transaction_c.grf` in your WAR file. It should be at the root of the classpath, i.e. right under `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: Hi David ..Thanks a lot .. Its working now.. I want to ask one question. If I used http inbound endpoint and deploy war file in tomcat then Is my app run successfully ??? Or I must have to use Servlet Inbound endpoint???

Comment: And I change in pom.xml <packaging>war</packaging> and compile but war file didn't create Is there any more step to create war file?

Comment: Hi David Now I am facing another issue..please help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912246/service-is-not-initialize-while-embeding-tomcat-with-mule-esb

Comment: If you deploy in a servlet container, then use servlet inbound endpoints, not HTTP inbound endpoints, otherwise Mule starts a second HTTP server inside the servlet container, which makes no sense.