# Service is not initialize while embeding tomcat with mule esb

Tags: tomcat, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I follow all the steps define in the following link

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+Mule+as+a+Service+to+Tomcat

Instead of

```
> <Listener
> className="org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener" />
```

I used

```
> **<Listener className="org.mule.module.tomcat.MuleTomcatListener" />**
```

And my tomcat also started. I also deploy my war file into webapps folder. I didn't get any error while deploying war file.. But problem is my service didn't initialize..

following is my flow file

```
<data-mapper:config name="CSV_To_List_Transaction_c" transformationGraphPath="csv_to_list_transaction_c.grf" doc:name="CSV_To_List_Transaction"/>
    <sfdc:config name="Salesforce" username="username" password="pwd" doc:name="Salesforce" securityToken="token"/>
     <flow name="javatestFlow1" doc:name="javatestFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="Custom" moveToDirectory="Backup" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_List_Transaction_c" doc:name="CSV To List&lt;Transaction_c&gt;"/>

        <sfdc:create-bulk config-ref="Salesforce" type="Transaction__c" doc:name="Salesforce">
            <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
        </sfdc:create-bulk>
        <idempotent-message-filter idExpression="#[payload.state]" doc:name="Idempotent Message"/>
        <custom-transformer class="com.org.Status" doc:name="Java"/>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="test..."/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>

<flow name="testforceFlow1" doc:name="testforceFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
            host="localhost" port="8090" doc:name="HTTP" path="download" />
         <flow-ref name="javatestFlow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</flow>
```

And my web.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>salesforce</display-name>
    <description>salesforce to ftp</description>



    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
        <param-value>javatest.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleRESTReceiverServlet</servlet-class>

        <!-- Responses from the servlet are of type HTML by default -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.mule.servlet.default.content.type</param-name>
            <param-value>text/html</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>testindex.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

After creating war file. My war file structure look like

```
Project_Name
    WEB-INF
        classes
            javatest.xml
            log4j.properties
            mule-app.properties
            mule-config.xml
            mule-deploy.properties
            com
                org
                    class files
            webapps
                demo    
                    WEB-INF
                        classes
                            all mapping files
                        web.xml
                    test.jsp
        lib
    META-INF
        MANIFEST.MF
    maven
        com.mycomp  
            project_name
                pom.properties
                pom.xml
```

I start my tomcat and try to run localhost:8090/download
But found This webpage is not available
I also tried by putting servlet-inbound endpoint but didn't get success...
How can I initialize my service????

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure Tomcat defaults to listening on port 8080. Have you tried  localhost:8080/download ?

Comment: yes .. it gives me eror.. I think the problem is in my war file structure

Comment: Why don't you use the listener recommended at step 2 of the guide you have linked? If you follow the guide, does it work? Also note that you are attempting to deploy Mule a service inside Tomcat. There's a much simpler path where you just wrap a Mule application as a WAR and deploy it as a web application.

Comment: And also use `servlet:inbound-endpoint` instead of `http:inbound-endpoint`, otherwise you are not using the web tier of your Servlet container so what's the point of deploying Mule in it?

Comment: If i use MuleXmlBuilderContextListener then my server didn't start. It gives me error... org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
Thats why I used MuleTomcatListener